# Is there a name for this mapping?

Tags: polar-coordinates, transformational-geometry

I wish to take a set of points described using Cartesian coordinates ($x, y$) and map them to a set of polar coordinates ($r, \theta$), such that $r = y$ and $\theta = x$. Thus horizontal lines become circles, and vertical lines become radial lines.

1) Is there a name for this transformation? I'm hoping for something catchy like **Polarisation**...

2) What will happen to an angled line such as $y = mx + c$ (where $c \ne 0$) under this transformation? (I'm guessing a hyperbola...)

Comment: As for $\;x\;$ there's not much problem, though many times it is customary to use angles in $\;[0,2\pi]\;$, but $\;y\;$ needs a major restriction as the polar coordinate $\;r\;$ cannot be negative.

Comment: $\theta = x(mod 2\pi)$ and $(r, \theta) = (-r, \theta + \pi)$ should do it

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the standard change of variable is just a function $f: (x,y)\mapsto (\sqrt{x^2+y^2} ,\arctan (\frac yx ))$ with conditions on inverse tangent because it should give different values depending on signs of $x,y$. Then the inverse function is $f^{-1} :(r, \theta ) \mapsto (r\cos \theta , r\sin \theta)$

Anyway, what you described is just pluggin in $(y,x)$ (as radius and angle) into the inverse function,

$$(\tilde x, \tilde y) = (y \cos x, y \sin x)$$

Where $(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$ is the new coordinates.

So the first equation shows that for the same $y$ values, any horizontal lines would be mapped to a circle. Whereas the same $x$ value (vertical line) would be mapped to the straight line $y=mx$.

Generally given $L=\{(t,mt+c):  \forall t\in \Bbb{R} , m,c \in \Bbb{R} \}$

This gives $ (\tilde x, \tilde y) = ((mt+c)\cos t, (mt+c) \sin t)$, which is a curve parametrized by $t$. Observe if $t$ increases, the radius increases, while the angle rotates continuously. So for example if $m,c >0$, the curve starts as $(c,0)$ and spirals outwards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about part (1), but I can provide an answer to part (2).

You have the "polarized" equation $r=a\theta+b=a\left(\theta+\frac{b}{a}\right)$. Notice that $r=a\theta$ is just an [Archimedes' spiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesSpiral.html), and the $\frac{b}{a}$ does a counterclockwise rotation of $\frac{b}{a}$ radians, so any non-horizontal and non-vertical line is just a rotated Archimedes' spiral.